# Change button title in section of tableview on specific row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have view controller in which there are multiple section of tableview. In section 0 I have multiple row . Each row having button named as Add Comments when I click on button it pushes me to other view controller having text field when i wrote something and press done button then through delegate I passes textfield data and set it in button title. But problem is my button present in all row changes value. I want only selected row in section changes its button title. below is my code of first viewcontroller

```
class MyTabViewController: UIViewController {
var addCommentsValueStore: String = "Add Comments"
@IBOutlet weak var tabTableView : ContentWrappingTableView!

 @IBAction func addCommentsAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let nextVC = MyCommentsRouter.getMyCommentsViewScreen() else { return }
        nextVC.passAddCommentsDelegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            let indetifier =  "MyTabTableViewCell"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: indetifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTabTableViewCell
cell.addCommentsButton.setTitle(addCommentsValueStore, for: UIControl.State.normal)
}
return cell
        }

extension MyTabViewController: AddCommentsDelegate{
    func passAddComments(instruction: String) {
        addCommentsValueStore = instruction
        print(addCommentsValueStore)
    }
}
}
```

below is code of second view controller:

```
import UIKit
protocol AddCommentsDelegate{
    func passAddComments(instruction: String)
}

class MyCommentsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var addCommentsTextField: UITextField!
    var passAddCommentsDelegate: AddCommentsDelegate?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
    }
    
    @IBAction func backActionClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func DoneActionClick(_ sender: Any) {
        let dataToBeSent = addCommentsTextField.text
        self.passAddCommentsDelegate?.passAddComments(instruction: dataToBeSent!)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by using `tag` on the cell button, you can fix your problem.

on your `cellForRowAt` delegate method, put this line:

```
cell.addCommentsButton.tag = indexPath.item
```

now you know exactly which button did select, then you can use this tag to specify which row in your tableView should change its title.

your implementation has some problems:

first of all, the `addCommentsValueStore` have to be an array of strings.

```
var addCommentsValueStore: [String] = []
```

then tell the delegate to show the right title:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: MyTabTableViewCell!
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTabTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTabTableViewCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.addCommentsButton.setTitle(addCommentsValueStore[indexPath.item], for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
    return cell
}
```

the `AddCommentsDelegate` should return the index too:

```
protocol AddCommentsDelegate {
    func passAddComments(instruction: String, atIndex: Int)
}
```

then every time you want to pass comment to another viewController, you should pass the index too.
by using this index, you will specify where you should change the row button title.

```
@UIBotton func DoneActionClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let dataToBeSent = addCommentsTextField[sender.tag].text
        self.passAddCommentsDelegate?.passAddComments(instruction: dataToBeSent!, atIndexPath: sender.tag)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: I am new to swift and i don't know how it will work can you describe more?

Comment: @Ajay I edit my answer and explain more, hop it will help you.